# How do I authorize an app script in a web interface?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, oauth-2.0, cors

I have a simple app script that searches drive for a folder named 'something' and lists the names of files inside if the folder doesn't exist it creates it.

```
function doGet() {
 var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('something');
 if (folders.hasNext()) {
  var files = folders.next().getFiles();
    var fileNames  = [];
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      fileNames.push(file.getName())
    };
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        'status': 'success',
        'output': fileNames
    }))

  } else {
    DriveApp.createFolder('something');
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
        'status': 'success',
        'output': 'folder created'
    }))
  }
}
```

I deploy the script as a web app, execute the app as myself, test it out using a fetch call from a react app in a browser and everything work as expected.

Then I republish as a web app, executing as the user accessing the web app. This time nothing works. I get the following error in the browser

> Access to fetch at
>   'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx4eQ60DziUy4hSjnJidW9WVwBsT_qruQHa_BrK508T4oD9ILY/exec'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I expected an error since there is no authentication. I set up google OAuth2 on the react app, added scripts and drive scopes, register the app in google developer console and set everything up so that I get an `accessToken` that I can send in the header with the fetch call to the google script.

But I still get the same error as above.

How am I supposed to authorize an app script app so that anyone can run it?

I am trying to create a web app with a `google` sign in button, when the user signins in it calls the `appscript` I deployed and searches their drive for a folder names 'something' so that I can display the names of files in my web app.

**This is not a cors issue, if I execute the web app as myself there is no cors problems and zero changes to the code. My question is regarding how I authorise an app script? I only mention the cors error because I was showing what I have tried so far.**

Comment: 1. Try setting X-frame options to Allow-all with htmlservice OR 2. use doPost() OR 3. Use a backend to fetch

Comment: So you are saying this is just a cors issue, what I am trying to do makes sense and is possible using appscript?

Comment: Isn't that what your error states? I don't see why not... But I'm doubtful whether you can bypass cors.

Comment: cors errors are usually a catch-all for any kind of error from an appscript deployed as a web app. Please help me understand why you think any of these solutions would work when my current app works if I execute it as myself. Doesn't it working rule out cors actually being an issue? Happy to try these, if you are sure they will help.

Comment: @tehhowch reopened

Comment: I can't guarantee anything, but I believe what you're trying to do is entirely possible and that this still is a cors issue or as the answer states `Google's error page does not include any CORS headers.`-> So, you have a error somewhere. You have to provide error logs(view>Stackdriver logging)

Comment: As I linked in comment on my answer, OP should probably review Tanaike's post on web apps: https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Answer (score 1):

You will receive a CORS error if any function in your call throws an exception, since you have no `try...catch` handler. When a deployed webapp [fails to return a valid response (i.e. either an `HtmlOutput` or `TextOutput`)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps), Google's error page does not include any CORS headers.

To prevent these "masking" CORS errors, wrap your web app entry points with `try...catch` so that the actual error can be reported.

Even without wrapping your webapp's entry points with `try...catch`, it is very likely that you are able to access the underlying error by viewing your project's Stackdriver logs / Stackdriver Error Reporting.

This is a simple example, demonstrating some event object validation to ensure that the request is from somewhere you care about & is well-formed, and then calls a function that may throw an exception for invalid / unauthorized operations. In either case, it returns an opaque user-facing response ("Sorry!") and for errors will generate a Stackdriver log. It cannot catch the exception that occurs for an execution time quota breach, since your script is simply killed.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  if (!e || !validate_(e)) {
    return fail_();
  }
  try {
    return walkDriveContent(...);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error({message: "Drive walk failed: " + err.message, stack: err.stack, error: err});
    return fail_();
  }
}

function fail_() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Sorry!");
}

function validate_(eventObj) {
 /** your code here that ensures this is a valid event object you can work with */
 // return true;
 //     or
 // return false;
}

function walkDriveContent(folderName) {
  /**
   * Your code that may throw exceptions here, but otherwise
   * returns TextOutput or HtmlOutput
   */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But does this means you are saying that my general approach is correct and I shoudl be able to authentcate a script by passing in teh access token in the header. there is nothing else I have to do?

Comment: @josh Off the top of my head, yes, if you've obtained an OAuth2 access token that contains the required scopes, then you can **execute** your web app as that user. You may or may not be able to **access** the web app as that user. I suggest updating your question to be about resolving the masking CORS error, and then when you have the underlying error pinned down, ask a new question about that. Probably you should review https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: I'm not too worried about cors, I'll figure that out or ask another question, this question is titled 'How do I authorize an app script in a web interface?'.

Comment: @josh Yes, that's the title, but then your question body is almost entirely about a CORS error. This answer of mine demonstrates how you can prevent getting that CORS error (and instead access the underlying error that created the CORS error).

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. I did my best to explicitly state that this is not a cors issue at the bottom of the question, and that I only mention the cors error because I was showing what I have tried so far. My concern is that I don;t want to spend ages fixing teh cors error if what I am trying to do in fundamentally not possible. Have you ever granted access to an app script app via a web app by passing in a token?